# ggarrange: combining multiple plots with shared y and x axis: arrange for only one shared y axis while keeping plots in same proportion

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, ggpubr

I used `ggpubr::ggarrange` to create a multiple plot with a shared y- and x axis. The only issue that I am having is that the first plot, which does have the y axis is smaller than the other 3 plots which brings the whole figure out of proportion.

I am therefore looking for a solution to display only one y lab without bringing the first plot out of proportion to the other 3 plots. Help is highly appreciated as I have been searching for a solution to this problem since quiet some time already.

My approach so far was to remove the y lab from plot (p) 2,3,4 and leave it on p1.

This is my code:

```
library(ggplot2)
  library(ggpubr)
  library(dplyr)
```

```
p1 <-  ggplot(arrange(ploughed1, Horizont), aes(Ferment, RAI_II,  fill = factor(Horizont, levels=c("4","3","2","1"))))+
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")+
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("#FF9933", "#CC6600","#663300","#000000"))+
    guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE))+
    labs(fill="Horizon")+
    ylim(0,200)+
    theme_bw()+
    facet_wrap(~compost)+
    theme(strip.text = element_text(size = 7),
          panel.spacing = unit(0.2, "lines"))+
    geom_col(position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE))+
    labs(x="Ferment", y = "RAI_II=Rooting*Scheme*Active",  title = "P- ")

p2 <-  ggplot(arrange(ploughed2, Horizont), aes(Ferment, RAI_II,  fill = factor(Horizont, levels=c("4","3","2","1"))))+
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")+
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("#FF9933", "#CC6600","#663300","#000000"))+
    guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE))+
    labs(fill="Horizon")+
    ylim(0,200)+
    theme_bw()+
    theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(),
          panel.spacing = unit(0.2, "lines"),
          strip.text = element_text(size = 7))+
    facet_wrap(~compost)+
    geom_col(position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE))+
    labs(x="Ferment",  title = "P+ ")+ 
    rremove("ylab")

  p3 <-  ggplot(arrange(reduced1, Horizont), aes(Ferment, RAI_II,  fill = factor(Horizont, levels=c("4","3","2","1"))))+
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")+
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("#FF9933", "#CC6600","#663300","#000000"))+
    guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE))+
    labs(fill="Horizon")+
    ylim(0,200)+
    theme_bw()+
    theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(),
          panel.spacing = unit(0.2, "lines"),
          strip.text = element_text(size = 7))+
    facet_wrap(~compost)+
    geom_col(position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE))+
    labs(x="Ferment",  title = "RT- ")+ 
    rremove("ylab")
  
  p4 <-  ggplot(arrange(reduced2, Horizont), aes(Ferment, RAI_II,  fill = factor(Horizont, levels=c("4","3","2","1"))))+
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")+
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("#FF9933", "#CC6600","#663300","#000000"))+
    guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE))+
    labs(fill="Horizon")+
    ylim(0,200)+
    theme_bw()+
    theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(),
          panel.spacing = unit(0.2, "lines"),
          strip.text = element_text(size = 7))+
    facet_wrap(~compost)+
    geom_col(position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE))+
    labs(x="Ferment",  title = "RT+ ")+ 
    rremove("ylab")
```

```
ggarrange(p1, p2, p3, p4, nrow=1, common.legend = TRUE)
```

### Output .png

Output image: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdiFQ.png)

I also tried to solve it in the ggarrange function, without removing the y lab and text in p2,p3 and p4, which had the same result.

```
ggarrange(p1, p2+ 
            theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(),
                  axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
                  axis.title.y = element_blank() ), p3+ 
            theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(),
                  axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
                  axis.title.y = element_blank() ), p4+ 
            theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(),
                  axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
                  axis.title.y = element_blank() ) , nrow=1,  common.legend = TRUE)
```

Comment: Please share your data to make your post reproducible using `dput(ploughed1)`. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If other packages are an option for you, I would suggest to make use of `patchwork`. Using some convenience functions to reduce the duplicated code and some random example data to mimic your real data:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)
library(dplyr)

ploughed1 <- data.frame(
  Horizont = rep(1:4, 4),
  RAI_II = runif(16, 10, 50),
  Ferment = rep(c("-", "+"), each = 8),
  compost = rep(c("- Compost", "+ Compost"), each = 4)
)

plot_fun <- function(x, title) {
  ggplot(arrange(x, Horizont), aes(Ferment, RAI_II, fill = factor(Horizont, levels = c("4", "3", "2", "1")))) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("#FF9933", "#CC6600", "#663300", "#000000")) +
    guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE)) +
    ylim(0, 200) +
    theme_bw() +
    facet_wrap(~compost) +
    theme(
      strip.text = element_text(size = 7),
      panel.spacing = unit(0.2, "lines")
    ) +
    geom_col(position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE)) +
    labs(x = "Ferment", y = "RAI_II=Rooting*Scheme*Active", fill = "Horizon", title = title)
}

remove_y <- theme(
  axis.text.y = element_blank(),
  axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
  axis.title.y = element_blank()
)
p <- list(
  plot_fun(ploughed1, "P-"),
  plot_fun(ploughed1, "P+") + remove_y,
  plot_fun(ploughed1, "RT-") + remove_y,
  plot_fun(ploughed1, "RT+") + remove_y
)
wrap_plots(p, nrow = 1) + plot_layout(guides = "collect")
```

[image]

Compared to `patchwork` where all facets are of the same width in each plot making use of `ggpubr:ggarrange` squeezes the facets in the first plot because of the `y` scale:

```r
ggpubr::ggarrange(plotlist = p, nrow = 1, common.legend = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: using `patchwork` did the deal, thank you very much!

Comment: I would like to add error bars on the stacked bars. I calculated the standard error for every treatment, i.e. bar, and tried to use `geom_errorbar` from the `ggplot` package. I tried to include it into the formular but the error bars are not showing up.
Any idea how to include error_bars in this scenario or why it is not working? 
Here the added code, everything else remained the same.
`+geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean-se, ymax= mean+se ), width=0.2,position =position_dodge(0.9))+`
Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi @lebe. Not sure whether I got you right. What I did: `x_error <- x %>% group_by(compost, Ferment) %>% summarise(mean = sum(RAI_II), se = sd(RAI_II))`. Note. I use the sum to put the error bars on top of the bars. For the plot: `geom_errorbar(data = x_error, aes(x = Ferment, ymin = mean-se, ymax= mean+se), color = "red", inherit.aes = FALSE)`. Maybe this helps.